# Convert a working and functional reactjs component to a class based component

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, typeerror

I am trying to figure out how to convert this functional React component in Visual Studio 2017 environment and using ASP.Net MVC framework
The code below works fine:

```
    var ProductGridRow = React.createClass({
        render : function(){
            return (
                <tr>
                    <td>{this.props.item.ProductName}</td>
                    <td>{this.props.item.Price}</td>

                </tr>
            );
        }
    });

    var ProductGridTable = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function(){
            return {
                items:[]
            }
        },
        componentDidMount:function(){
            // Fetch data via ajax *@
            $.get(this.props.dataUrl, function(data){
                if(this.isMounted()){
                    this.setState({
                        items: data
                    });
                }
            }.bind(this));
        },
        render : function(){
            var rows = [];
            this.state.items.forEach(function(item){
                rows.push(
                    <ProductGridRow key={item.Id} item={item} />);
            });
            return (
                <table className="table table-bordered table-responsive">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Product Name</th>
                        <th>Price</th>

                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {rows}
                    </tbody>
                </table>);
        }
    });
    ReactDOM.render(
        <ProductGridTable dataUrl="/home/getProductData" />,
        document.getElementById('griddata')
    );
```

However when I try to convert the above code to have Class based component in line with the present practice and when I have tried this:

```
    class ProductGridRow extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                productRow: []
            }

            render()
            {
                return (
                    <tr>
                        <td>{this.props.item.ProductName}</td>
                        <td>{this.props.item.Price}</td>

                    </tr>
                );
            }
        }
    }

    class ProductGridTable extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                productList: []
            };
            this.loadData = this.loadData.bind(this);
        }

        componentDidMount(){
                       // Fetch data via ajax 
            this.loadData();
        }

        loadData() {
            $.get(this.props.dataUrl,
                function(data) {
                    if (this.isMounted()) {
                        this.setState({
                            items: data
                        });
                    }
                });
        }


            render(){
                var rows = [];
                this.state.productList.forEach(function(item) {
                    rows.push(
                        <ProductGridRow key={item.Id} item={item}/>);
                })
                return (
                    <table className="table table-bordered table-responsive">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Product Name</th>
                            <th>Price</th>

                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {rows}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>);
            }
        }



        ReactDOM.render(<ProductGridTable dataUrl="/home/getProductData" /> 
        ,document.getElementById('griddata'));
```

but it ends up with "Uncaught TypeError: this.isMounted is not a function". Not sure as to what should be the correct code after conversion. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

`isMounted` is deprecated. Just remove the `if (this.isMounted()) {...}` block around your call to `setState` inside of your AJAX success handler callback.

https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works OK without that error.

Comment: However I now have Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at setRequestHeader (jquery-2.2.0.min.js:4)
    at e (jquery-2.2.0.min.js:4)
    at Fb (jquery-2.2.0.min.js:4)
    at Function.n.param (jquery-2.2.0.min.js:4)
    at Function.ajax (jquery-2.2.0.min.js:4)
    at Function.n.(:53965/anonymous function) [as get] (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js:4:12281)
    at ProductGridTable.loadData (Product.jsx? [sm]:92)
    at ProductGridTable.componentDidMount (Product.jsx? [sm]:88)
    at CallbackQueue.notifyAll (react.js:869)